# jquery if is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code.. the problem is that the CSS is not applying in both div's but only in the first one `#main-wrapper`

I have the same code but this time in a button press and its working, but with the if statement only the single works.. im not sure if the codes is somewhere wrong please help ... i tried to put the script in the end of the body tag but still nothing

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("#expand") > -1) {
  $( "#main-wrapper" ).animate({ 'width':'984px' }, 'slow');
  $( "#sidebar-wrapper" ).animate({ 'display':'none' }, 'slow');   
}
```

Comment: can you bring up the console (f12) and tell us the error ?

Comment: You can't animate `'display':'none'`. You could animate the opacity, or use slideUp.

Comment: Try to play with `opacity`

Comment: "i have the same code but this time in a button press and its working, " yes but your indexOf fails. Read my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't animate `'display':'none'`.

You could animate the opacity:

```
$( "#sidebar-wrapper" ).animate({'opacity':0}, 'slow', function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

or, as suggested by Me.Name in comments:

```
$( "#sidebar-wrapper" ).fadeOut('slow');
```

or use `slideUp`:

```
$( "#sidebar-wrapper" ).slideUp();
```

Comment: well spotted, just curios, does opacity not still reserve the actual DOM space ?

Comment: S/He says it works with a button... the if return FALSE cause hash jumps with javascript

Comment: @Pogrindis Yes, that's why I call remove at end

Comment: ah i missed that, creative!

Comment: yeap thats work! before i did use  $("#sidebar-wrapper").hide("slow"); but didnt work cause the script tag was over #sidebar-wrapper but i dint tried it after i but the script tag on the bottom, yeap the problem is the display:none !, very much thank you!

Comment: Perhaps I missed something in the requirements, but why not use `fadeOut`?  ( `$( "#sidebar-wrapper" ).fadeOut('slow');` )

Comment: @Me.Name You're right, this is basically the same but is more concise